# hitTestObject method fal passing newar corner

Tags: actionscript

two rectangle and given instance name `w1` and `w2` then how can pass two of my rectangle very close to each other ,when i tried to pass it stuck at corner but as much i saw the are far from each other

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1139552

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveplayer);
var left,right,up,back:Boolean;


// both rectangles were given  instancename as w1 and w2 and drawn on stage manually


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN ,keypress);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP ,keyup);
//gray box movement key
function keypress(event:KeyboardEvent  ):void
{


          if (event.keyCode == 37)
          {
                    left = true;


          }
          else if (event.keyCode==38)
          {
                    up = true;


          }
          else if (event.keyCode==39)
          {
                    right = true;


          }
          else if (event.keyCode==40)
          {
                    back = true;


          }
}




function keyup(event:KeyboardEvent ):void
{


          if (event.keyCode == 37)
          {
                    left = false;
          }
          else if (event.keyCode==38)
          {
                    up = false;




          }
          else if (event.keyCode==39)
          {
                    right = false;


          }
          else if (event.keyCode==40)
          {
                    back = false;


          }


}
//grey box movement
function moveplayer(event:Event ):void
{


//hit test
          if (w1.hitTestObject(w2))
          {
                    trace("hit");


//function call to repulse back
                    repulse();
          }
          else
          {
// function call to move
                    go();
          }




//rotation
          if (left)
          {
                    rotateit("left");
          }
          else if (right)
          {
                    rotateit("right");
          }












          function rotateit( direc:String)
          {


                    if (direc == "left")
                    {
                              w1.rotation -=  1;
                    }
                    else if (direc == "right")
                    {
                              w1.rotation +=  1;


                    }


          }
}






//move function
function go()
{
          if (up)
          {
                    var x2:Number = w1.x;
                    var y2:Number = w1.y;
                    //trace(x2,y2)
                    var speed:Number = 5;
                    w1.x +=  speed * Math.sin(w1.rotation * 2 * Math.PI / 360);
                    w1.y -=  speed * Math.cos(w1.rotation * 2 * Math.PI / 360);


          }
}
//repulsion function


function repulse()
{




          var x1:Number = w1.x;
          var y1:Number = w1.y;
          trace(x1,y1);
          var speed:Number = 5;
          w1.x +=   -  (speed * Math.sin(w1.rotation * 2 * Math.PI / 360));
          w1.y -=   -  (speed * Math.cos(w1.rotation * 2 * Math.PI / 360));
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase better in the form of a question.  Tell us what us what is wrong, don't say go test.

Comment: actually i have two rectangle converted to symbol and given name as w1 and w2  i want to w1 rectangle to pass near the corner of the w2 rectangle but they collide farfrom each other if u make them pass  near the corner